# Miracle flatness on Wikipedia's "Cohen--Macaulay ring"

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, schemes, affine-varieties, flatness

In Wikipedia's article on Cohen–Macaulay rings, the following geometric version of miracle flatness is stated, see [this link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cohen%E2%80%93Macaulay_ring#Miracle_flatness_or_Hironaka%27s_criterion):

> Let $X$ be a connected affine scheme of finite type over a field $K$ (for example, an affine variety). Let $n$ be the dimension of $X$. By Noether normalization, there is a finite morphism $f$ from $X$ to affine space $\mathbb A^n$ over $K$. Then $X$ is Cohen–Macaulay if and only if all fibers of $f$ have the same degree.

Exercise 18.17 of Eisenbud's commutative algebra book is cited, but this exercise actually has more assumptions and says something that, for me, sounds completely different. Is the above statement even true? Or is this a typo and there should be "dimension" instead of "degree"?

Comment: The morphism is finite, so the dimension of each fiber is 0.

Comment: Oh, yes of course, sorry...

Comment: And now I see how it relates to Eisenbud's statement. Since the dimension is $0$, length equals degree. But still Eisenbud assumes that $X$ be equidimensional and that $f$ be surjective.

Comment: If $f$ is not surjective some fibers are empty, hence have degree zero.